# I want to allow incoming traffic on a specific port like ssh and block all outgoing traffic in firewalld

Tags: linux, firewall, firewalld

I'm using Firewalld,

- I want to block all the outgoing traffic.
- And allow all incoming traffic or SSH connection for specific IPs.

I'm able to block all the outbound traffic and it is working by using this document https://forums.opensuse.org/t/block-outbound-traffic-except-for-one-destination/152140/4

But, it is dropping all the connections for incoming traffic also. I want to all allow incoming traffic.

Any help would be much appreciated.